# log4perl: grouping messages

Tags: perl, logging, log4perl

I'm using `log4perl` to log messages from a `perl` script. With `mwe.pl` as below, then I receive the following (desired) output in `test.log`

```
INFO: some information
      more information
```

My current implementation uses:

```
my $logmessage = "some information\n";
$logmessage .= "more information";
$logger->info($logmessage);
```

Notice in particular that I have  specified the line break manually using `\n`, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way that I can achieve my desired output (`test.log`), without having to scaffold my logging input?

## `mwe.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);

my $logger = get_logger();
$logger->level($INFO);

my $layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new("%p: %m{indent}%n");
my $appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::File",
    filename => "test.log",
    mode     => "write",
);

$appender->layout($layout);
$logger->add_appender($appender);

my $logmessage = "some information\n";
$logmessage .= "more information";
$logger->info($logmessage);

exit(0);
```

Comment: why do you not want to have the `INFO` on every line? I would have to look at the implementation internals, but maybe you can build something that wraps `->info` to behave the way you want when you pass in a list. Then you can have `@logmessages` instead of `$logmessage`.

Comment: On the other hand, that would break the default behavior that each argument is one whole message.

Comment: @simbabque there are 'groups' of log messages that naturally go together, and are for information. I find it easier to read if these groups are formatted in the way that I've outlined above. if every single line has `INFO` or `WARN` or something else, then I find myself ignoring them, which (for me) takes away some of their value

Comment: Why not simply make your own wrapper to hide the newline part that you don't like?

Comment: Would like to see such a wrapper

Comment: How do you decide which messages go into a group, of all possible `info` ones?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would consider removal of scaffolding. (After all, some means of communicating that two messages are related is needed.) Are you asking for something like `$logger->info("some information"); $logger->moreinfo("more information");`?

Comment: I think something like logger->info(...,heading) for lines that have INFO and logger->info(...) for non-headings. Or, perhaps, logger->info-heading and logger->info.

Comment: You need to tag me (`@ikegami`) for me to get notified.

Comment: Your wrapper: When you receive a heading call, flush your buffer (join the contents with newlines, then send the buffer to the actual logger), then add the new data to the buffer. When you receive a non-heading call, add the new data to the buffer. Flush on destruction.

Comment: @ikegami that sounds like a nice approach, I'd certainly be interested in seeing it. I like zdim's answer, and am using it with, for example `$logger->info("*...")` for 'headings' and `$logger->info("...")` for 'non-headings' (I've adjusted the anonymous subroutine accordingly)

Comment: Re "*I'd certainly be interested in seeing it.*", hum? I just showed it.

Comment: Re "*I like zdim's answer*", aye, probably simpler. I was simply answering your question as to how one would write a wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to add [custom "cspecs"](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.49/lib/Log/Log4perl/Layout/PatternLayout.pm#Custom_cspecs) to your `PatternLayout`.  Using an API

> ```
> Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::add_global_cspec(
>     'A', sub { ... }
> );                    # can now use %A
> ```

where this needs to come before the call to `new` which can then use the `%A` specifier.

This can be set up in [configuration](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl-1.36/lib/Log/Log4perl/Config.pm) instead, as shown in linked docs. Or `add_global_cspec` method can be called on the `$layout` object (but I couldn't figure out the interface.)

The anonymous sub receives

> ```
> ($layout, $message, $category, $priority, $caller_level)
> ```
>
> layout: the PatternLayout object that called it
>       message: the logging message (%m)
>       category: e.g. groceries.beverages.adult.beer.schlitz
>       priority: e.g. DEBUG|WARN|INFO|ERROR|FATAL
>       caller_level: how many levels back up the call stack you have 
>           to go to find the caller

what can be used to implement criteria for formatting the prints.

Here is a simple example custom-specifying the whole format

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);

my $logger = get_logger();
$logger->level($INFO);

Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::add_global_cspec( 
    'A', sub { return ( 
        $_[1] !~ /^more/                 # /^more/ taken to indicate 
           ?  "$_[3]: "                  # the continuation criterion,
           :  ' ' x length $_[3] . '  '  # or start with 'INFO: '
    ) . $_[1]
});

my $layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new("%A%n");

my $appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::File",
    filename => "new_test.log",
    mode     => "write",
);

$logger->info('some info');
$logger->info('more info');

$logger->info('info');
$logger->info('more and more info');
```

which prints

```
INFO: some info
      more info
INFO: info
      more and more info
```

Such a custom specifier can of course be combined with the provided ones.

Since the list in `info(...)` is joined by the logger into a string that is passed along to appender(s) we can decide on the heading in the caller with an apparent interface

```
$logger->info('*', "... message ...");  # * for heading (add INFO:)
```

where the first string above is whatever the regex in our `cspec` looks for.

This formats each log line based on its content. A more rounded option is to [write your own appender (FAQ)](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.39/lib/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.pm#How_can_I_write_my_own_appender?), which is a rather simple class where you can keep and manipulate lines as needed. See an example of [bundling messages (FAQ)](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.39/lib/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.pm#How_can_I_bundle_several_log_messages_into_one?), for instance.

Finally, a proper way to fine-tune how messages are selected is by adding a [category](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.47/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm#Categories). Then you can pull a new logger and configure it to display `INFO:` (for the header line), while the rest of messages in that group go by the other logger, configured to not display it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937303/4653379) for a simple example.

The downside is that there is now a lot more to do with loggers, appenders, and layout, and all that for only a small tweak in this case.

If these don't fit the bill please clarify how you decide which prints are to be grouped.

Comment: Many thanks, I like this a lot. Thanks for the links as well, most informative. I'll wait a few days before accepting and awarding the bounty to maximize exposure.

Comment: @cmhughes  Great to hear that it helps, thank you for saying that. I just noticed your comments and added an idea for an "interface" for that. Thank you for the attribution.

Comment: @cmhughes  I added another approach, that is in fact a "proper" way to fine tune these kinds of things. (It is likely too heavy-handed for this purpose, unless there is more in reality.)